# Storing large amounts of data from GET request in Angular using jsstore

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, indexeddb

I'm having an issue using jsstore with large data from a GET request. So for starters, I'm receiving an array upwards of 9000+ json and I need to store them in jsstore for persistence (in order to avoid multiple GET requests for large data). In doing so I'm having an issue with an observable not resolving in time.

This is located in my authService

```
async getData() {
  this.loadToken();
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authToken
  });
  const data = this.http.get(this.ROUTE, {headers: headers})
    .pipe(map(res => res));

  return await data.subscribe((vals: any) => {
    return this.storeDataInDB(vals.data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  });
}

async storeDataInDB(data) {
  return await this.DBService.storeData(data);
}
```

This is in my DBService

```
  async insert(data: any) {
      return await this.connection.insert({
        into: this.tableName,
        return: false,
        values: data
      }).then(function(rowsInserted) {
        if (rowsInserted > 0) {
          console.log('Successfully added all records!');
        }
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

This is the error I receive from jsstore. I know it's from the observable not resolving in time due to a similar issue I had before.

> message: "Null value is not allowed for column 'unit_number'"
>   type: "null_value"

I've tried so many things at this point, I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend converting promises to observables as soon as possible. The mix and match can be confusing. I don't think the size of the data should matter, unless you are getting some kind of timeout?

Maybe try this:
DBService

```
  insert(data: any) {
      return fromPromise(this.connection.insert({
        into: this.tableName,
        return: false,
        values: data
      }));
  }
```

authService

```
getData() {
  this.loadToken();
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authToken
  });
  this.http.get(this.ROUTE, {headers: headers})
    .pipe(
       tap(vals => console.log(vals)),
       switchMap(vals => this.DBService.storeData(vals.data)),
       tap(rowsInserted => console.log(rowsInserted)),
    ).subscribe(rowsInserted => console.log(rowsInserted), err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: I added what you said and I still get a null value error. I'm thinking that the observable is not resolving fast enough

Comment: I dont think so, although I could be wrong. Observables shouldn't have any problem with how long they run, whenever they get back, the subscribe block runs. But, I edited my answer with a couple extra console logs that could help debug the issue. Can you let me know what they print?

Comment: This is what returned exactly.

{data: Array(9573), success: "true"}
request pushed: insert
request executing:insert
request finished : insert
{message: "Null value is not allowed for column 'development_name'", type: "null_value"}message: "Null value is not allowed for column 'development_name'"type: "null_value"__proto__: Object
undefined

Comment: I tried your solution with the one I wrote before that works, and it doesn't work. :/ I'm at a loss of words.

Comment: I think the problem is actually with the data thats being returned. The first console log is showing you that the data is returning before an error happens. The error itself seems like it wants a a value for development_name but it is null inside the data itself

Comment: I took off the validations to check if it's null, and still returns the same thing. :/

Answer (score 0):

The error message - {message: "Null value is not allowed for column 'unit_number'" type: "null_value" } means - there is null value in data for column unit_number & you have added notNull in your database schema.

If you want to skip data check for inserting data, you can use skipDataCheck with your insert query like this or api `bulkInsert` if you prefer-

```
connection.insert({
        into: this.tableName,
        return: false,
        skipDataCheck:true,
        values: data
})
```

For more info, check out insert api - http://jsstore.net/tutorial/insert/.